# How to create an Ubuntu Desktop kickstart CDROM on 12.04?

Tags: kickstart

I want to create a kickstart image through CDROM on Ubuntu 12.04, but I am not having success.

Comment: This worked for me on 12.10: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/unattended-ubuntu-installations-made-easy.html and the link is from 2010 :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also had to create an unattended install using Ubuntu 12.04,2 LTS. First I tried to work with the desktop version of Ubuntu but I could not even start the installer in text mode. My experience is that the graphical version just doesn't obey the kickstart file and preseed didn't seem to work either. I am not sayint they don't work, but I couldn't bring them to work.

My solution is to use the server version of Ubuntu and running the installer in text mode. It reads my ks.cfg and ks.preseed file just like I wanted, I could add extra packages to my ISO image, and it works like a charm.

You did not describe what kind of problems exactly you are having, but if you still do, describe them in detail!